# Entering data into database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I am trying make a program to first show all results in the database then get someone to enter a match result, but when i try to insert the data i keep getting this error:

```
* Cannot execute insertion! *
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)
at results.UserEntryInsertion.main(UserEntryInsertion.java:57)
```

here is my code for the insertion:

```
package results;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UserEntryInsertion
{
    private static Statement statement;
    private static Connection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newHomeTeam;
        String newAwayTeam;
        int newHomeScore;
        int newAwayScore;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                "jdbc:odbc:FootballData","","");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfEx)
        {
            System.out.println("* Unable to load driver! *");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlEx)
        {
        System.out.println(
                    "* Cannot connect to database! *");
        System.exit(1);
        }

    System.out.println("\nInitial table contents:\n");
    displayTableContents();
    System.out.print("\nPress <Enter> to continue...");
    keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nNew Home Team ");
    newHomeTeam = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("\nNew Away Team ");
    newAwayTeam = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("\nNew Home Score ");
    newHomeScore = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nNew Away Score ");
    newAwayScore = keyboard.nextInt();

    try
    {
        String insertion = "INSERT INTO Results VALUES("
                        + newHomeTeam + ",'"
                        + newAwayTeam + "','"
                        + newHomeScore + "',"
                        + newAwayScore + ")";
        statement.executeUpdate(insertion);

        System.out.println("\nContents after insertion:\n");
        displayTableContents();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx)
    {
        System.out.println("* Cannot execute insertion! *");
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    closeDown();
}

static void displayTableContents ()
{
    ResultSet results = null;

    try
    {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        results = statement.executeQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM Results");
        while (results.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Home Team"+ results.getString(1));
            System.out.println("Away Team:"+ results.getString(2)); 
            System.out.println("Home Score:"+ results.getInt(3));
            System.out.println("Away Score:" + results.getInt(4));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx)
    {
        System.out.println("* Error retrieving data! *");
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

static void closeDown()
{
    try
    {
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx)
    {
        System.out.println("* Unable to disconnect! *");
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You ought to use the SQL INSERT statement where you give the column names as well as the column values.  You can be sure you're putting the values in the correct columns.

Answer (score 1):

```java
String insertion = "INSERT INTO Results VALUES("
                        + newHomeTeam + ",'"
                        + newAwayTeam + "','"
                        + newHomeScore + "',"
                        + newAwayScore + ")";
```

Some of the strings are quoted (newAwayTeam/newHomeScore), while some are not. If an unquoted string contains a question mark `?`, you will get the exact error you're showing.

You should really use the parameter capability of [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) though, it will save you from things like quotes in your strings which may mess up the SQL, something more along the lines of;

```
String insertion = "INSERT INTO Results VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
statement.setString(1, newHomeTeam);
statement.setString(2, newAwayTeam);
statement.setString(3, newHomeScore);
statement.setString(4, newAwayScore);
statement.executeUpdate(insertion);
```

(assuming they're all supposed to be strings, there are other set methods for other data types)

Comment: `Too few parameters` doesn't mean maybe there is/are more field(s) must be inserted ? or it's caused by  `'` ?

Comment: @AzadOmer It means that the statement is expecting a parameter (a question mark makes it expect one), and since there is none in the SQL string itself, it most likely comes from keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

newHomeTeam and newAwayScore are without ''.
Try this:

```
String insertion = "INSERT INTO Results VALUES('"
                    + newHomeTeam + "','"
                    + newAwayTeam + "','"
                    + newHomeScore + "','"
                    + newAwayScore + "')";
```